# How to get the current Devise user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The Devise documentation (along with all SO answers) says I should be able to access my current user with `current_user`. Duh.

However, check out what I'm getting:

```
 current_user                                                                                         
=> true
```

EDIT: Okay, I had indeed defined my own `current_user` method and forgot to remove it. So I can get the current user from the model and from the controller. How do I get the current user from within a feature spec?

```
pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::FacebookLogin>)> current_user                                                                                 
NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::FacebookLogin:0x00007fb90cdf9450>
Did you mean?  current_url
```

Comment: Did you maybe write your own method to define `current_user` somewhere? Potentially as a helper? There's not enough information here to really divulge further. You should be able to access `current_user` in your layouts/views.

Comment: Are you using `:confirmable`?

Comment: You should be able to do `method(:current_user).source_location` to get the file path & line that defined this `current_user` method (and see if it was re-written at some point).